# Employee database script is not running in Mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am new to the mysql , I downloaded the employee database zip file extracted it. Then I run the script file but its always giving me error that this file is already being used.

Here's a snap of error.

> MySQL Workbench
>
> Run SQL Script
>
> [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:
> 'C:\Users\Kushagra\AppData\...\tmpd26qry86,cnf'

Can someone please explain how to solve the issue? Is there any another way to import ?
I'm using
MySQL Shell 8.0.25
MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

Comment: Where did you extract the file to? its attempting to import a file in Temp which doesnt seem right...

Comment: I extracted the zip to another local hard disk (Not C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding a lot of solutions and none seemed to affect I downgraded my MySQL workbench version.

Initial version : 8.0.25

Downgraded version (worked fine) : 8.0.20

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the background process of MySQL using task manager? It may acquire the process and preventing the script from execution.

Comment: Its showing there are two MySql workbench going on.

Comment: I believe simply terminating background processes would work. I'm assuming you are using a personal computer and in that case, you may restart the DB services and DB listener.